# Memory allocation of a vector inside a function while building matrices with Eigen::Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, matrix, pass-by-reference, eigen

I created a class that reads a vector and copies the result to a desired matrix (in fact it changes a string to a vector and the parsed vector is of unknown size, but I post a simplified code).

The function `getMatrix` reads a vector, copies it to the vector `containerVector` and using a function `Map` reshapes it to a matrix, `containerMatrix` passing-by-reference. However, after executing the function, the object `containerVector` is destroyed, so as far as I understand  [Eigen Map tutorial](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html), `containerMatrix` points to nowhere (or to some random location in memory). So, when I execute the second function, setModelMatrix, it should either return some memory allocation or segmentation fault error. However, it works properly, so it looks like the values were copied, not passed. Is it safe to use Map in that way, or am I just lucky? Is my understanding correct, or is there a better solution?

Note: I will use the function `getMatrix` few times for different vectors, and copy the obtained values to different matrices, which are not included in presented part of code. The comma initializer didn't work for my problem.

```
class MatrixModificationClass
{
 private:
 //two matrices defined
    MatrixXd containerMatrix; //a container
    MatrixXd modelMatrix;   //the proper matrix

 public:
    MatrixModificationClass();

//a function to create vector and map it to matrix 
 void getMatrix(std::vector ivector)
 { 
  std::vector<double> containerVector;
  //This is only a simplified example, in reality I change string to a vector
  containerVector=ivector; 
  int instances=10, columns=10;  //size of matrix

  containerMatrix = MatrixXd::Map(&containerVector[0], columns, instances);
  containerMatrix.transposeInPlace();
 };   

 void setModelMatrix()
 {
     modelMatrix = containerMatrix;
 };
};

main()
{
 std::vector newVector;
 MatrixModificationClass Example;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
   newVector.push_back(i);
 Example.getMatrix(newVector);
 Example.setModelMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is safe (though sub-optimal).

In this line

```
containerMatrix = MatrixXd::Map(&containerVector[0], columns, instances);
```

An `Eigen::Map` object which points to `&containerVector[0]` is created, and then its contents are copied to `containerMatrix` (a `MatrixXd` object always owns its data). Then the `Eigen::Map` is destructed (it runs out of scope at the `;`), while `containerVector` is only destructed at the end of the method.

As a simple optimization, you can avoid the `transposeInPlace()`, by directly assigning

```
containerMatrix = MatrixXd::Map(&containerVector[0], columns, instances).transpose();
```

Depending on how you "change string to a vector", you could probably directly write into `containerMatrix` (you need to resize it to the correct dimensions before doing that).
You could also store the `containerVector` inside your class (instead of `containerMatrix`) and create an `Eigen::Map` on the fly whenever you need it.
The most efficient solution depends on your actual use-case, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, `adding .transpose()` could optimize the code.
I don't think that writing directly to `containerMatrix` is possible in my case, since I tried it before. The input matrices are tab-separated data files of unknown dimensions. I use `getline` and `stringstream` to import the data.